# Does iPhone 6 / 6 Plus simulator supports changing of Display Zoom mode?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, iphone-6

How to change Display Zoom feature in iPhone 6 and 6 Plus simulators? 
Original iPhone 6 and 6 Plus have this feature in Settings -> Display & Brightness -> Display Zoom (View) with values Standard and Zoomed.

Comment: What does this feature do? I don't have an iPhone 6, and the simulator doesn't have it, so I'm curious. Thanks.

Comment: @matt It changes how the icons look on the home screen. "Zoomed" the icons and the labels under them are a bit bigger than "Standard".

Comment: Just 2 links to understand what it all about:
http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/09/use-display-zoom-iphone-6-plus.html http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: Okay, so this is about much more than the icons on the home screen. It changes the aspect ratio _of my app_. Basically the iPhone 6 turns into an iPhone 5s in real time.

Comment: @matt Display Zoom is not available as an option in the current Xcode 7 iOS simulator settings. However, it is actually possible to 'simulate' Display Zoom when running your app in the simulator. See below.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**As of Xcode 12** (and perhaps earlier) `Settings -> Developer -> View -> Zoomed` (tap Set) will adjust the simulator to show with Display Zoom. This is helpful as the `iPhone 11 Pro`, `iPhone 12 mini`, `iPhone 12`, and `iPhone 12 Pro` all run at a previously unused resolution of 320 x 693. For more information check out this excellent [article](https://hacknicity.medium.com/how-ios-apps-adapt-to-the-various-iphone-12-screen-sizes-e45c021e1b8b) by Geoff Hackworth.

[image]

Comment: There is no such option in the iPhone 6 Plus simulator

Comment: This option does exist within the simulated phone for iPhone 12 Mini etc.

Comment: @David Try one more time. I am seeing the setting for the iPhone 12 Mini (Xcode 12.2). `Settings` is the Settings app **running in the Simulator instance**.

Comment: @David I added an image to ensure the steps are clear - hope it helps.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. If you run into trouble, make sure you notice his last instruction to tap the "Set" button after selecting the display mode.

Comment: With Xcode 12.4, there is no such option on iPhone 8 and 8plus simulators for iOS 13.  I haven't tried other combinations.

Answer (score 23):

Display Zoom is not available in the simulator (as of Xcode 6.0).

Comment: Velery Pavlov's link in comments of question shows that zoomed iphone 6 = iphone 5s and zoomed iphone 6plus = standard iphone 6

Comment: @i40west Display Zoom is not available as an option in the current Xcode 7 iOS simulator settings. However, it is actually possible to 'simulate' Display Zoom when running an app in the simulator. See below.

Comment: Looks like Display Zoom was added recently in the Settings app in the Simulator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758930

Answer (score 8):

The answer is correct, Display Zoom is not available as an option in the current Xcode 7 iOS simulator settings. ***However***, it ***is*** actually possible to 'simulate' Display Zoom when running your app in the simulator.

**Background**

When building a typical project for iPhone, you generally specify a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file and/or launch images in `Images.xcassets` for the iPhone 4/4s (`2x`), iPhone 5/5s (`Retina 4`), iPhone 6/6s (`Retina HD 4.7`) and iPhone 6+/6s+ (`Retina HD 5.5`) and set those details in the project's settings. (See image below.)

When Display Zoom is turned ‘on’ for a iPhone 6/6s device, the device runs the app as if it was running on an iPhone 5/5s sized screen, upscaling the app x1.172 to fit the iPhone 6/6s display. (Similarly, when Display Zoom is turned ‘on’ for a iPhone 6+/6+s device, the device runs the app as if it was running on an iPhone 6/6s sized screen, upscaling the app to fit the iPhone 6+/6+s display.)

> Note - The following instructions require the removal of some launch screen image files. You might wish to attempt these changes on a duplicate of your Xcode project.

**Simulating Display Zoom on the iOS Simulator**

To simulate Display Zoom for example using the iPhone 6 simulator in Xcode:

1 - Remove the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file.

2 - Remove both the `Retina HD 4.7` and `Retina HD 5.5` launch images in `Images.xcassets`. (Make sure to keep the `Retina 4` launch image.)

3 - Remove the reference to the ‘Launch Screen File’ in your Xcode project’s settings, under ‘General’, under ‘App Icons and Launch Images’.

4 - Select the iPhone 6/6s simulator, and then 'Run' your app.

**Running your app**

When the simulator runs your app, it will detect that no launch images are present for iPhone 6/6s, so it will presume it must be an iPhone 5/5s app and launch it into the simulator upsampling a iPhone 5/5s sized screen to fit the iPhone 6/6s screen, just as the Display Zoom setting would display it!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't necessary anymore - follow the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758930/126855