# Is it possible to simulate zoomed mode of iphone6+ in Xcode6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

Is it possible to simulate zoomed mode of `iphone6+ in Xcode6`?
I can not find the "Display" Setting in the simulator.

Comment: just delete your LaunchImage for iPh6 (if you are using Asset Catalog); if not - change from LaunchScreen.xib to Asset Cataog and remove the coresponding LaunchImage

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to do this in the iphone simulator. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977305/does-iphone-6-6-plus-simulator-supports-changing-of-display-zoom-mode)

hope this helps!