# How to turn on Display Zoom in iOS Simulator for iPhone 6/6s or iPhone 6+/6s+

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, optimization, ios-simulator

Is it possible to turn on Display Zoom in the Xcode iOS Simulator for iPhone 6/6s or iPhone 6+/6s+ so that it is possible to test and optimize using that mode? On an actual device Display Zoom can be turned on in Settings > Display & Brightness however that option isn't listed in the iOS Simulator settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does iPhone 6 / 6 Plus simulator supports changing of Display Zoom mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977305/does-iphone-6-6-plus-simulator-supports-changing-of-display-zoom-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display Zoom is not available as an option in the current Xcode 7 iOS simulator settings. ***However***, it ***is*** actually possible to 'simulate' Display Zoom when running your app in the simulator.

**Background**

When building a typical project for iPhone, you generally specify a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file and/or launch images in `Images.xcassets` for the iPhone 4/4s (`2x`), iPhone 5/5s (`Retina 4`), iPhone 6/6s (`Retina HD 4.7`) and iPhone 6+/6s+ (`Retina HD 5.5`) and set those details in the project's settings. (See image below.)

When Display Zoom is turned ‘on’ for a iPhone 6/6s device, the device runs the app as if it was running on an iPhone 5/5s sized screen, upscaling the app x1.172 to fit the iPhone 6/6s display. (Similarly, when Display Zoom is turned ‘on’ for a iPhone 6+/6+s device, the device runs the app as if it was running on an iPhone 6/6s sized screen, upscaling the app to fit the iPhone 6+/6+s display.)

> Note - The following instructions require the removal of some launch screen image files. You might wish to attempt these changes on a duplicate of your Xcode project.

**Simulating Display Zoom on the iOS Simulator**

To simulate Display Zoom for example using the iPhone 6 simulator in Xcode:

1 - Remove the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file.

2 - Remove both the `Retina HD 4.7` and `Retina HD 5.5` launch images in `Images.xcassets`. (Make sure to keep the `Retina 4` launch image.)

3 - Remove the reference to the ‘Launch Screen File’ in your Xcode project’s settings, under ‘General’, under ‘App Icons and Launch Images’.

4 - Select the iPhone 6/6s simulator, and then 'Run' your app.

**Running your app**

When the simulator runs your app, it will detect that no launch images are present for iPhone 6/6s, so it will presume it must be an iPhone 5/5s app and launch it into the simulator upsampling a iPhone 5/5s sized screen to fit the iPhone 6/6s screen, just as the Display Zoom setting would display it!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did not work for myself. Do you have some further findings about this?

Comment: This isn't necessary anymore - follow the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758930/126855